# Replace Strings with IDs in Excel

Tags: excel, lookup

I have a Microsoft Excel worksheet that has hundreds of rows of items.  The category column in this items worksheet is filled with category names, which are duplicated since it's a many-to-one relationship of items to categories.  I would like to replace these category strings with IDs from a second worksheet that has a unique list of the category names paired with IDs.  So, the common link between the two is the category name.

How can I do this in Microsoft Excel?  Does it involve making a vba macro?

Comment: How about convert it into a proper relational database?

Comment: My wife is creating data for me to load into an sqlite database.  She's not a programmer. :/

Comment: Thanks everyone for the advice on VLOOKUP/LOOKUP calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, as the comment suggests, I think a good idea wouls be to move this to a database, even MS Access will suffice. Lets say you can not do that, so business rule that you require this to saty in excel.

OK, so lets start.

- From the sheet with the Items data,
  copy the entire column containing the
  Category strins, and paste this into
  a new sheet.
- Use the Remove duplicates command to
  ensure that you only have unique
  values in this new sheet.
- Now, to the right *(must be right, we will use this in a VLOOKUP later)* of this new column,
  create a column that contains 1..N,
  simulating Autonumber.
- Now on the original sheet, insert a
  new column to the right of the
  current Category column. Use VLOOKUP
  to retrieve the values from the
  Autonumber sheet. Something like this
  `=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!$D$1:$E$6,2)`

Now after you have checked that all your IDs seem correct, you can remove the Category column from the Items sheet if you wish so.

**I would still recomend using a database for this X-)**

Answer (score 3):

Use `VLOOKUP`.

[image: https://xe8.xanga.com/cf0f240006531262266720/w209023740.png]
<sub>(source: [xanga.com](https://xe8.xanga.com/cf0f240006531262266720/w209023740.png))</sub>

(You have to *sort* the category names for it to work.)

Comment: Or use INDEX(id_list, MATCH(name, name_list, 0)) or use VLOOKUP(name, names_and_ids,2,__FALSE__), which doesn't require that the list be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You need one of the LOOKUP functions. Here's [an article on this topic from Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324986). And [this is another one](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/TablesAndLookups.aspx) with more details and examples.

Note that using LOOKUP you'll be able to create a new column with the IDs next to the category names. If this is a one-off operation, you can then just replace the category column with that new ID column.